# Lose of data updating PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have asked one of my hostings to update the version of PHP and MySQL and they have replied telling me to be sure I have a backup of my databases as well as of the content of the page because during the update some data can be lost.

Is this just a way to cover their back in case of any incompetent doing bad their job? Or can it really result in a potential lose of data for some reason?

I am not really on the mod of downloading all the site, which is quite big and with thousands of images, and I was wondering which are the probabilities of suffering lose of data in this operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal procedure of any hosting company to inform their clients to perfom a backup before they touch the server. I think its more to do with technology. Things can go wrong regardless of how well the person is trained. I advice you in addition to making this backup, to have a regular backup schedule for your website in case things go wrong in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a question that anybody can really answer here.
Normally updating the versions of php and MySQL shouldn't cause any problems but like with everything in life - it can go wrong... J

So you can never be mistaken to have a recent backup at hand.